# Is there a test for KRACK (devices and routers)?

Tags: defense, krack

After Heartbleed was announced, a number of tests popped up that let me test if a server I was connecting to was patched, unpatched or unknown. For example, https://filippo.io/Heartbleed/

Is such a test possible for KRACK? Including checking...

- my **device** [1]

  - my **device** that I updated over an unknown wifi connection
- the **router** I am connected to (but don't control)
- the **router** I own

[1] I have other ways of finding this out, but here I'm thinking of J. User who hears scary news and just wants to know if their laptop/phone is vulnerable

Comment: It's worth noting that there are *lots* of bugs in the KRACK paper, so there may need to be a lot of different checks.

Comment: @Polynomial I'm trying to find what the flaws in the paper are, could you possibly link me to a write up on them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Test scripts will indeed be published by the original author <strike>but are not available yet</strike>.

As stated [by the author](https://www.krackattacks.com/#tools):

> We have made scripts to detect whether an implementation of the 4-way
>   handshake, group key handshake, or Fast BSS Transition (FT) handshake
>   is vulnerable to key reinstallation attacks. These scripts will be
>   released once we have had the time to clean up their usage
>   instructions.

I expect the linked page to be updated once the script become available, so check it regularly.

---

The author just [published](https://twitter.com/vanhoefm/status/928117439631642625) the [scripts to test the devices and access points](https://github.com/vanhoefm/krackattacks-scripts).

Answer (score 2):

This post gives full instructions to check AP for KRACK ATTACK that support FT.
http://rootsaid.com/krack-test/